# Maximum update depth exceeded (not using setState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a virtualized table using `MaterialReactTable`. I try to set the columns' width depending on the content size, but when I use my function that returns the size needed for the tab cell, I get this error after navigating a bit through the table :

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

The point is that inside this function, there is no setter, so the infinite re-render cannot come from the function itself.

In another way, I tried to replace the 'GetColumnWidth' function call by a row value (e.g. 20, 42, ...) and there were no issue: the table worked perfectly.

Here are the parts of the code related to the problem :

```
// format : [{..}, {..}, ...]
const copyData = myInputTable;

// Return a dictionary with the form -> columnKey: columnwidth,

const getAllColumnWidth = () => {
    const widthDict = {};
    for (const key in copyData[0]){
        widthDict[key] = GetColumnWidth(copyData, key);  // Here is the issue
    }
    return widthDict;
}

// Data is the full table -> [{..}, {..}, ...]
// key is the key of the column concerned (1 in each object of data)
// The goal of the function is to get the longest string's length of the column

function GetColumnWidth(data, key){
    if (data == undefined || key == undefined) {
        return 42;
    }

    const longChar = "ABCDEFGHIJKLNOPQRSTUVXYZ";
    var i = 0;
    var maxLength = 0;
    for (const line of data){
        var len = 0;

        if (line[key] === null || line[key] === undefined) {
            continue;
        }

        for (const lettre of line[key].toString()) {
            // Here I'm just defining the different sizes depending on the character

            if (longChar.indexOf(lettre) !== -1) {
                len += 0.26;
            } 

            if (lettre === 'W') {
                len += 1;
            }

            if(lettre === 'M') {
                len += 0.85;
            }

            if (lettre === 'm') {
                len += 0.80;
            }

            if (lettre === 'w') {
                len += 0.66
            }

            if (lettre === ' ') {
                len += 0.55;
                continue;
            }

            len++;
        }

        // Save the length if it's the longest string ever seen in the column
        if (len > maxLength) {
            maxLength = len;
        }
    }

    const coeff = 10;
    return 20 + maxLength * coeff;
}
```